# How do I build OpenCV's single module (e.g. legacy) for my development in Ubuntu?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I revised some source code of OpenCV's `legacy` module. My project is coded based on the new legacy module and I want to debugging it. One way that I can think out is using my revised legacy source code to **replace** the original legacy module, then **compile and reinstall** the whole OpenCV. I think this way is too waste of time and other modules(e.g. `imgproc`, `highgui`, etc) haven't any change and don't need to be reinstalled. I think there must have an easier way to solve it.

My developing environment is `VIM` && `GDB` && `opencv 2.4.13`. I am a green-hand of `linux-opencv`. How do I build OpenCV's single module in Ubuntu? If I want keep the original legacy module and the new legacy module in case of other usage, how should I do?

Comment: i don't think that's feasible to do. There are too much dependencies and you will have to figure out each one of them to do it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Thanks for your answer. You mean I must reinstall the whole opencv project even I did just a little revision.

Comment: i am not 100% sure but i pretty much think that it will be very tough to manage depecdencies

Comment: I doubt your assumption, suppose you built `highgui`, `imgproc` modules, the include file [`cv2.hpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp) would have the include paths of those modules, and again when you build `core` module, then it would override the `cv2.hpp`. You can Do what you want to, But it won't be smooth. You may manually need to edit some include files and copy `.so` files as well.

Comment: @ZdaR All right. I think maybe I have some misunderstanding in how opencv build && run. I'll install the different version for different opencv sources and change the environmental variables for different application. I think it is the best way.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to actually build a single module without building the entire source from the beginning. I guess you would have followed this procedures to install OpenCV in your machine [OpenCV Installation in Linux](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).

After the modifications in OpenCV's legacy module, you can build just that module by using the commands.

```
# Go to the build directory. If you followed the tutorial I shared then it is the release folder
cd release

# And build only the module you want to (For example, legacy model as in your case) 
make opencv_legacy    
sudo make install
```

Comment: Am I need to use the 'sudo make install' to install the original OpenCV to my pc? Or I just need to execute directly the make command and replace legacy source code, then run 'make opencv_legacy&&sudo make install'?

Comment: replace the source code and then build using the command 'make opencv_legacy&&sudo make install'